# Ubuntu 16.04 starts only in recovery mode

Tags: boot, drivers, grub2, recovery-mode

If I start my laptop I can see only a black screen and nothing happens. After restarting again I can chose recovery mode from GRUB. It looks like the video driver is missing, bc the movies in VLC player flicker, and of course suspend does not work anymore.

Here are the (kernel) red lines from journalctl -b
If you need any more information (e.g.:full boot log), please let me know.

[image]
[image]
[image]

**sudo lshw -C display**

```
  *-display UNCLAIMED     
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 07
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:d0000000-d0ffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: Display controller
       product: Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330 / M430 / R7 M520]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 83
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d1300000-d133ffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:d1340000-d135ffff
```

[image]

**What I have tried**

in *sudo gedit /etc/default/grub* I have tried this combinations (after changing the file I run update-grub), but

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash radeon.modeset=0"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash radeon.modeset=1"
```

After restarts I see the same error:
[image]